# MSDN blog links are broken, what should we do now?

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Links to MSDN blog pages (e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx) direct you to [a page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/) that states:

> MSDN and TechNet blog sites have been retired, and blog content has been migrated and archived here.

effectively rendering these links broken.

When searching for [`url:blogs.msdn.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ablogs.msdn.com) on Stack Overflow, we see the following:

> 47,838 results

Does this mean that there are almost 50 thousand posts on SO with broken MSDN blog links? If so, what is to be done?

N.B. I am unsure if *every* link to blogs.msdn.com is broken, at least all the ones I tried are.

Comment: Sigh. Microsoft has done it again. When will their system administrators learn that cool URIs don’t change? Yes, there are likely thousands of broken links to Microsoft blogs in SO posts, along with hundreds of links to Microsoft Connect (which were broken some time back by the obsoleting of Connect with no archive), and thousands of links to MSDN documentation that does not properly redirect to its new home. What do we do? I don’t know. URL rewriting with a bot *may* be an option for SE staff, but that requires we can find a stable mapping. Unlikely.

Comment: Definitely an issue. Historically MSDN has generated a decent amount of link rot. Sometime you can find them in the web archive (archive.org) and use those links. Other times, you are just out of luck.

Comment: @CodyGray I guess MS sys admins are not allowed to install Apache mod_rewrite ....

Comment: Microsoft [has it](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS too, @rene...

Comment: In the meantime, fixing the links (if possible) as you come across them is valid. You could maybe do a few edits for posts that are highly upvoted and/or get a lot of traffic but you don't want to flood the Active page with these edits unless folks decide it's worth a group effort to fix all of these posts (like a burnination request).

Comment: The epicly facepalming bit is that 5 or 10 years back MS started creating (IIRC URL shortened) forward links intending that they could serve as safely hardcodable links into external documentation (ex Visual Studio); and then promptly broke them just like they have with every other URL on their collective sites every few months when someone gets bored and decides to completely redo the site hierarchies.  I'm half convinced doing so is an annual review goal for MS PHBs?

Comment: I've never really understood how this is Stack Overflow's problem to fix. MSFT broke the links. If they don't feel that it's worth their time to preserve the links, why should SO? In any case, posts which reference blogs should be useful even without the links, right? Right?!?

Comment: @HereticMonkey agreed that there's no good way to mass fix it; and given MS's long history of breaking all their links would be only a short term fix.  My SOP when finding them is to search on the URL text.  80-90% of the time Google can figure out where MS moved it to, or failing that go to the [wayback machine](archive.org] to find a mirror of the page and then update the individual question/answer with a working link.  More broadly, this is why any answer needs to be able to stand on its own without any linked content.

Comment: I guess my point is, why are we doing MS's work for them? Why not leave them broken? Maybe if enough people start complaining to MS about them breaking their links they'll wise up. Maybe not, but in that case, they look like the idiots.

Comment: I agree it isn’t our fault, @Heretic, and that Microsoft looks like idiots for repeatedly breaking links. But having answers with dead links *does* reduce the overall quality and usefulness of our content for future viewers, so if there’s some way we can realistically address this, it makes sense for us to do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I would like to complain to MS, but it's useless. Some users have already done that on GitHub, but all that MS says is "we added some redirects, but you have to life with the rest being broken". Microsoft, like all big companies, has an efficent way of ignoring the needs of its own users... So either we're stuck with the current situation or we do our best to improve it ourselves and do the stupid work of fixing the links (again).

Answer (score 26):

I have some experience in [fixing broken links](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) and have set up a script which transforms these links: it turns out most (but not all) links can be fixed with some regex substitution:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx (not working)
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two (working)

Some links are still dead, and then the script tries to find the latest [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) copy. Results of the script can be monitored [via my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=revisions), though I have more scripts [to fix other types of broken links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337404/295232) as well.

> I am unsure if every link to blogs.msdn.com is broken, at least all the ones I tried are.

When I wrote this, links to Raymond Chen's [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) were still working (but redirected to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/). Nowadays, even those are broken.

Comment: Thank you for your work here, this seems like the best way forward for mass correction without a massive manual effort. I have a few questions - Do you have any idea what percentage of links can be rewritten easily? What does your script do if there is no available Wayback Machine copy? Should the rewritten links include the `/en-us/` locale or should they be agnostic to allow for automatic locale assignment?

Comment: @CallumWatkins I have no hard figures, but I estimate ~70% can be rewritten, ~20% has a Wayback Machine copy and ~10% are lost forever (and the script doesn't touch those - maybe I can collect those links and ask later if anybody has a suitable replacement for them). I doubt (m)any blogs have been translated, so I'm not worried about a default locale.

Comment: @Glorfindel: If your link checker includes `wp-login.php` in the URL, you should assume the link replacement failed.  See for example revision 5 on https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2632844/revisions

Comment: @Brian thanks for the ping. This seems to be exclusive to Eric Lippert's blogs - I pinged him, he probably knows what's best :)

Comment: Thanks for doing this! The last couple of edits here look weird though https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/55203/revisions - for some reason it is adding wayback machine links to links that are already wayback machine links and where the existing wayback machine link was still accessible