# Update 4guysfromrolla.com links with their archive.org version

Tags: support, status-completed, broken-link

The website 4guysfromrolla.com used to contain a lot of pages with tips for SQL, classic ASP, etc., but sometime after October 2021, it has been abandoned and now contains gambling stuff.

This leaves a lot of links here on Stack Overflow to point to the gaming scam pages instead of the wanted information. But (for the pages I tried) the page is on archive.org.

Is there a way to rewrite these links to the copy at archive.org?

Related: is there a way to request the latest version of a page before a certain date on archive.org?

Comment: What if we deleted those answers that leaned so heavily on a link from this site instead?  As in, if the answer isn't sufficient enough to stand on its own two feet without this link or work to redirect others to this link, what actual value does the answer have?

Comment: Ouch, [1780 posts linking that domain](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%224guysfromrolla.com%22&searchOn=3) on Stack Overflow alone :-(

Comment: @Makoto We can and should delete answers that consist primarily of links.  However, that's going to leave quite a few that use the links merely to *supplement* an actual answer and which now link to a spammy gambling site.

Comment: How to edit all of the posts that contain (now dead) eval.in demo links? a Stack Overflow search shows [2549 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eval.in&searchOn=3).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402281/1595451

Comment: Yes, you can get the most recent version prior to a certain date by providing that date in the URL with which you request the archived page. For example, [this request for a 2021-04-15 version](//web.archive.org/web/2020415/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070208-1.aspx) results in showing the 2021-01-21 capture, which was the most recent prior to 2021-04-15 and does not result in getting the [2021-04-16 capture](//web.archive.org/web/20210416023142/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070208-1.aspx), which was made the day after the date which is being requested. cc @Glorfindel

Comment: @Makyen right, thanks. I somehow assumed Leif would want to use the API, don't know why though ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Well, hopefully, archive.org will update their API to allow making requests such that one can find the most recent capture prior to a certain date. As a provider, if you want people to use your API, rather than scrape pages/requests, then it's a good idea to have the API cover everything one can do on the site, or at least have some other way to accomplish it (e.g. provide a full list of all captures). Note: I really haven't looked at their API much, so don't know if there's an alternate method to accomplish this.

Comment: @Makyen I did, and I have to scrape the page to handle certain oddities (such as following 302 redirects), but 99% of the time the API works fine for me.

Comment: What do people _not like_ about fixing broken links?

Comment: FWIW, I've pinged [one of the 4 guys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160830/scott-mitchell) and made them aware of this topic.

Comment: From my personal experience of a similar task ([Fixing up now-bad links to use Wayback Machine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402392/1115360)), albeit only for something like 250 Q&As, there are often other links (e.g. to MS documentation) that could do with being updated at the same time. Also, if you're doing it manually it offers a chance to weed out link-only answers, and make grammar corrections and formatting improvements. You need to find the latest archive.org links that are still valid.

Comment: Hi guys, this is Scott Mitchell, I was one of the four guys from Rolla. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the site, the domain name, etc., and haven't since sometime in 2001. It's unfortunate that the site has been abandoned by whatever company owned it, as there were thousands of articles and FAQs.

Comment: @Scott Same thing happened to me with aspfaq . com (don't go there now).

Comment: This update is complete, however [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%224guysfromrolla.com%22&searchOn=3) will still show them (because the wayback URL _includes_ the original URL). But if you click through to any of those results you should see the links do point to web.archive.org.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Please post that as an answer to collect some upvotes :-)

Comment: @Bergi nah, it’s ok, I never would have been able to do what I did without Glorfindel’s work.

Answer (score 31):

First of all, thanks for reporting this!

I have a script which is able to search for posts containing those links, which checks *all* links in those posts, and applies some [transformation rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406565/4751173) on them, or ask the Wayback Machine for a copy (if needed).

This morning, I let it do an analysis (so no edits yet) on basically all posts found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%224guysfromrolla.com%22), and it would make 1762 edits. The [overview of replacements it would make](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/eae0c400a559b1ab95cb756f09c995d9) is too big to fit in a single Stack Exchange post, so ironically I have to rely on a link to an external provider (GitHub) to host it. (You'll need to scroll to the right to see the replacements and the affected post IDs.)

I spot-checked a couple of Wayback Machine copies, and they are all from before November 2021 so they seem to be fine.

When the script edits posts, it will bump them to the front page, so I put a rate limit on it; the defaults are 8 edits at a time on Stack Overflow (3 on other sites, and only 1 if it needs to suggest edits); each script runs once every three days. There are a couple of them currently active on Stack Overflow; next to the aforementioned one for MSDN blog links, there's also one for [stuffed up links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337404/295232), one for [Geeks with Blogs](https://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/), etc.

Meanwhile, links on other sites (except Server Fault, I'll let the script do that) have been fixed, and I'm glad @AaronBertrand is willing to do all the work on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a way to output the post ID(s) (e.g. in a comma-separated list for each URL)? With the IDs it would be relatively easy to batch update from the database side. But it's way too intrusive for me to _find_ those posts by brute searching with `LIKE` since I don't have the power of Elastic. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess so, but that would require a (non-trivial) change in the script. (Also, the script looks network-wide, so I'd have to output each site individually.) Let me see what I can do in the next few days...

Comment: Thanks! I didn't expect it would be simple. But armed with the IDs, I can remove all the work of editing, and also prevent the bumps.

Comment: Alternatively, we could start by just targeting a single site at a time, if that simplifies anything about the output, I'll have to handle them all separately anyway. For sites like [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), there were only 2 4guys links, and I fixed them manually.

Comment: Yeah, there are only two dozen or so instances outside of SO, so that's the only site which benefits from a programmatic approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated the GitHub gist with post IDs (and the results are now SO-only).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that update, made it _relatively_ easy to perform from my side. I had to manually edit a small handful, so a couple of bumps, including the ones that your output say failed. If you spot any 4Guys links that still point to the original site, please let me know.

Comment: @AaronBertrand we have a similar case on Photo.SE and some related sites in the network, details [on the Moderators Team](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/q/5086/23) (not sure if you're a member, but you should be able to get access :P) I haven't done all necessary preparations yet, just checking if you could help.

Comment: @Glorfindel Would you still have a copy of this script? I ask because a similar situation has occurred. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427348/dreamincode-links-redirect-to-a-gambling-site-how-can-we-handle-posts-that-li?cb=1

Comment: @NickODell thanks for the ping, I think the trick described in the answer will do a good job already and left a comment there.