# "DreaminCode" links redirect to a gambling site. How can we handle posts that link to this domain?

Tags: discussion, support, hyperlinks

I noticed [this edit which I rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35332199) had the edit comment as:

> ATTENTION. the link redirects you to a scam slot machine site

Sure enough, it does.  I flagged this post in question for a mod to review.

I then did a search of [`url:dreamincode.net`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Adreamincode.net) on the site, and there are a lot of posts that link to this site.  I guess this domain has "new owners" now, and now is being used for a gambling site.

What should we do with any posts that link to this domain? Should I flag them all? Strip out the link from them all? I didn't want to perform any actions yet since editing out links might look weird to those who are unaware...

Comment: The good\* news is that around the network there aren't many more links to the domain. [Searching over the entire SE](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Adreamincode.net) shows 1498 results, so a little bit more than SO. Which would be easier to handle. We probably still need to figure out what to do on SO, though. \* I mean, not really *that* good

Comment: To find all results using Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange search, you need to separately search as all of normal text, in URLs, and in code. For SE, the results are [`"dreamincode"`](//stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dreamincode%22) (44 results), [`"dreamincode.net"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dreamincode.net%22) (27 results), [`url:"dreamincode"`](//stackexchange.com/search?pagesize=100&q=url:%22dreamincode%22) (1,501 results), and [`code:"dreamincode.net"`](//stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22dreamincode.net%22) (2 results). Searching additional permutations may be necessary.

Comment: @Makyen Ironic - the one code search for the URL links back to a SO Meta post that says _"even if the original link rots away (unlikely seeing as it's dreamincode.net, but always a possibility)"_

Comment: Similar issue that happened last year: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420009/update-4guysfromrolla-com-links-with-their-archive-org-version

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I guess the course of action would be to update them to their archived version, if they exist.  But on this scale, we'd probably want to use the tool that SE Staff have to do bulk link edits.

Comment: See also [Dream.In.Code Shutting Down](https://web.archive.org/web/20220116044604/https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/421898-dreamincode-shutting-down/) for background on the shutdown.

Comment: @Makyen do we to place a [meta-tag:status-review] on this?  I thought that was procedure but the [SE Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313243/how-to-find-and-or-change-a-set-of-hyperlinks-on-a-site/314169#314169) that describes this process doesn't say that... pretty sure that how we've done it on Arqade ([example](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16816/3)).

Comment: @user4581301 on one foot, while fighting lions and starting a business selling shoes, etc. etc. 

Answer (score 22):

[This blog post](https://blog.ielliott.io/rip-dreamincode) claims that:

> Dream.In.Code has been thoroughly archived on web.archive.org

So perhaps one option is to change the URL to the one in archive.org?

I tested a few links (by simply prepending `https://web.archive.org/web/20220122225559/` - the number will change itself via redirection) and it seems to work. It's nice that the operation required might be able to be automated.

Comment: That's a nice trick - it will indeed resolve to the last snapshot captured on or before 2022-01-22 22:55:59. That means staff can do a mass update with their [find and replace tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169/295232). Of course, some links might still be broken then - I may be able to have one my scripts analyze that.